# Why the UIWebView have one grey block area?

Tags: xcode, uiwebview

I am using Xcode8.1.
I put one ViewController within one Navigation Edit as snapshot, and add one UIWebview in it.
I have added four constraints to make the UIWebView to take the total screen.
But, it display strange with one grey block area.
Any experts know how to get off it?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The web view will leave the room for the navigation bar free and give the standard behaviour of "shining through". So just pull the web view up right to the top (i.e. don't leave that extra space for the navigation bar.

Comment: My VC is under UINavigaitonController. That's why I place the webview under nav bar.